# Unable to mock Micronaut repository in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm still fairly new to Micronaut.

I've been struggling to figure out why I keep running into this testing error:

```
AuthenticationHelperTest > testCreateAccount() FAILED
    java.lang.NullPointerException: accountRepository.save(accountModel) must not be null
```

I can manually test my endpoint via POSTMAN and it creates an account perfectly fine in the database but fails on a test case.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId

class AuthenticationHelperTest {
    private val accountRepository = Mockito.mock(AccountRepository::class.java)
    @Test
    fun testCreateAccount() {
        val account = Account(
            ...
        )
        Mockito.`when`(accountRepository.save(account)).thenReturn(Account(
            ...
        ))

        val sut = AuthenticationHelper(accountRepository)

        val accountDto = AccountDto(
            ...
        )

        val result = sut.createAccount(accountDto)

        Assertions.assertEquals(1, result.id)
    }
}
```

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: mockito ins't necessary. You need to user [@MicronautTest](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/) in your class signature and [@MockitoBean](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#_using_spock_mocks) for your mocks. Here i have some [examples](https://github.com/j1cs/drugstore-demo/blob/master/backend/src/test/groovy/me/jics/StoreControllerSpec.groovy#L124)

Answer (score 1):

Micronaut provides a`@MockBean` to declare a mocked in a test.

```java
@MicronautTest
class SomeTest {

    @Inject AccountRepository bean;

    @Test
    public void testSomething(){}

    @MockBean(AccountRepository.class) 
    AccountRepository mockedAccountRepository(){
       return mock(AccountRepository.class);
    }
}
```

There is [an complete example using `@MockedBean`](https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox/blob/master/data-jpa-post-service/src/test/java/com/example/PostControllerTest.java). But from my experience, the Mockbean only works on an interface.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to run your test with `MockitoExtension`

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class AuthenticationHelperTest
```

And use `@Mock` annotation for `accountRepository`

```
@Mock
private val accountRepository;
```